# Define nested value from one interface in another interface in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

If I want to define a property in interface `Two` and have it be the same as a property in interface `One`. I can do it with this:

```
interface One {
  parent?: {
    child?: boolean;
  };
}

interface Two {
  parent?: One['parent']
}
```

But how can I copy a nested property? I would expect this to work:

```
interface Two {
  parent?: One['parent']['child']
}
```

but it errors:

```
Property 'child' does not exist on type '{ child?: boolean | undefined; } | undefined'.
```

Comment: The problem is that `One['parent']` is optional, so its type is `{child?: boolean | undefined}` **`| undefined`**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Exclude` to remove the `undefined` part from `One['parent']`, allowing you to access `['child']`:

```
interface Two {
  parent?: Exclude<One['parent'], undefined>['child']
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIhQbwFDOQBzignAH4AuZHPPBAC2ABsATC5AIwHtPGI4QA3LmQBfISOzZQkWIhQAVAO6cqwwsTKUAogA8EjAK7MIAHnQQA2gHJ1JMFYC6AGmQGQxmKAjMAfNfpMzI7YIkA)

Comment: I'd only gotten as far as diagnosis (realizing the problem was the `undefined`) when you posted the solution. :-)